# How to find out the computed value of an element's lang attribute in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I sometimes need to find out the computed value of the HTML `lang` attribute (the element's language). I'm using jQuery. For example, in the following code I'd like to know the computed lang of the `<p>` element, and I would expect the value `he`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>lang test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div lang="ar">
            <div lang="he">
                <p>Hallo.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Doing `$( 'p' ).attr( 'lang' )` returns nothing, probably because the `<p>` element doesn't have its own lang attribute.

This code seems to do the right thing:

```
 $( 'p' ).closest( '[lang]' ).attr( 'lang' )
```

Is this functionally correct? And is there a better way to do it in jQuery, in pure JavaScript or with another JavaScript library?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you wrote the best way. Ofcourse, if you use jQuery in other code a lot.

Comment: .prop() could be used instead of .attr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to write a recursive function:

```
function getLanguage(node) {
  if(node.lang) {
    return node.lang;
  } else if(node.parentNode) {
    return getLanguage(node.parentNode);
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

Recursion might be inefficient at times, but here it probably does not matter.

If you need the information for various elements in a document very frequently, efficiency might be relevant, and then you could traverse the entire document tree and add a new property, indicating the “computed language” to each node.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin should do the job.  It only considers the first element in the jQuery object.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.lang = function() {
         if (this.length) {
             var node = this[0];
             while (node) {
                 if (node.lang) {
                     return node.lang;
                 }
                 node = node.parentNode;
             }
         }
    };
})(jQuery)
```

It will return `undefined` if no `lang` attribute is found.

Comment: Lol. You use jQuery but forget about `closest` and jQ selectors like in original post. You're funny, dude

Comment: @moredemons  jQuery `[lang]` attribute selectors may not work if the language property was added as a property instead of an attribute.  It depends on whether the browser mirrors the property into the attribute.  Chrome does, I don't know about other browsers.  In any event, this would be more efficient than using an attribute selector.